# How to switch to a different <div> and locate an element using WebEelement

Tags: selenium, webdriver

My page has the following source code:

```
<body>
    <div id="nsm-header" class="ericssonApplicationBar">
    <div id="nsm-body">
    <div id="nsm-footer">
<body>
```

I need to locate an element in **"nsm-body"** and when I click on it, a new window/pop-up opens and there will some additional tags apart from above three. So now page source looks like this:

```
  <body>
       <div id="nsm-header" class="ericssonApplicationBar">
       <div id="nsm-body">
       <div id="nsm-footer">
       <div id="content_0:installNE_shade" class="rf-pp-shade" style="z-index:10001;">
       <div id="content_0:installNE_container" class="rf-pp-cntr e-dialog " 
  <body>
```

Now my element is present in a div with ID `content_0:installNE_container`. When I say `findElement` I get a StaleElement exception.

Now how do I avoid this and access the element? I tried fetching **windowHandles** and then switching to the current window but nothing happened. I also tried with `switchTo.defaultContent`, but still no use.

Please help me out.

Comment: When you get the StaleElement exception, does it come immediately after finding an element with findElement, or are you trying to act on an element previously found?

Comment: Hi, when I say:new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("content_0:_c27_:_e1797_:_e1798_"))); and end my @Test after this statement, my Junit passes, now when I write again driver.findElement(By.name("content_0:_c27_:_e1797_:_e1798_")).click(); at this statement I am getting staleelement exception. what I am not understanding is that while writing an explicit wait my Junit passes so does this mean that element is already found. Please note that this found element after the page source has the additional div tags.

Comment: Hi all, Please help me out, I am stuck with my testing here, what can I do to go further?Is there no way out?

Answer (score 1):

```
new Actions(driver).click(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='pop-up']"))).perform()
```

Comment: Hi, do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

Three thoughts:

I notice in the comment you left that the first time you find the element you use the **id** `(By.id‌​("content_0:_c27_:_e1797_:_e1798_"))`, and the second time you use the **name** `(By.name("content_0:_c27_:_e1797_:_e1798_"))`. Additionally, I don't see a name tag in the code you pasted, so that could be the problem...

I'm not sure if this will help, but the wait condition you have set `until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElelentLocated)` only means that the element is present, not that it can be acted upon (because maybe it's not visible now, etc), which is why a `presenceOfElelentLocated` works, but the `.click()` on the very same element may not. In Java there is also an `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` or `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(WebElement element)` documented [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) and in C# there is `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible` documented [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementIsVisible.htm) that makes sure that the element is not only present in the code, but also has height greater than 0 (which usually means that it can also be acted upon). Maybe using something like that can help in this instance?

Lastly, I would check to make sure that the id you are using `"content_0:_c27_:_e1797_:_e1798_"` is not dynamically generated. If it is, it you'll need to use some other identifier to locate the element reliably.

Comment: Thanks AutoKarma! Actually name and id are same, I tried with both thats what I meant. And how can I check whether id is generated automatically? I did check that element is visible, even though I am not able to click on it. I am getting the exception. And if at all any element is not visible, does it mean that the xpath could be wrong? how do I make that element visible.

Comment: Will you paste your code? It would be helpful to see what you've written and exactly what you're trying.